# Time complexity of merging two lists while preserving order

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion

I have two lists `l1` and `l2` of possibly unequal sizes (say, `m` and `n`). I wrote an algorithm to find out all ways `l1` and `l2` can be merged while preserving their order.

```
l1 = ["NYC", "LA"]
l2 = ["A", "B"]

output:
[['NYC', 'LA', 'A', 'B'],
 ['NYC', 'A', 'LA', 'B'],
 ['NYC', 'A', 'B', 'LA'],
 ['A', 'NYC', 'LA', 'B'],
 ['A', 'NYC', 'B', 'LA'],
 ['A', 'B', 'NYC', 'LA']]
```

`NYC` always comes before `LA`. `A` always comes before `B`.

Basic idea of algorithm: Append one item from `l1` to `temp`, recurse on remaining part of the lists. Do the same for `l2`.

Code (python3):

```
def merge(l1, l2):    
    temp = [] # temporary buffer 
    res = [] # final result
    mergeHelper(l1, 0, l2, 0, temp, res)
    return res

def mergeHelper(l1, start1, l2, start2, temp, res):
    if start1 >= len(l1) and start2 >= len(l2):
        res.append(temp.copy())
        return

    if start1 < len(l1):
        temp.append(l1[start1])
        mergeHelper(l1, start1+1, l2, start2, temp, res)
        temp.pop()

    if start2 < len(l2):
        temp.append(l2[start2])
        mergeHelper(l1, start1, l2, start2+1, temp, res)
        temp.pop()
```

**Question**: What's the time/space complexity? I suspect it might be $O(2^{n+m})$ as we have two choices for every iteration.

I figured out the recurrence relation is: `T(m,n) = 1 + T(n-1, m) + 1 + T(n, m-1)` but unable to reduce it further.

Comment: What are the complexities of `append` and `pop` ?

Comment: Notice how this is equivalent to the counting the number of north-east lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$. Or $(n,m)$

Comment: @YvesDaoust `append` and `pop` are both `O(1)`

Comment: `pop` can be O(n). And what about the cost of implied memory allocation/deallocations ?

Comment: "as we have two choices for every iteration": mh, no. After a number of iterations, one of the lists will exhaust and only one choice remains. This may sound unimportant, but it changes the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to combine an ordered list of size $n$ and an ordered list of size $m$ into one ordered list of size $n+m$ in a way which keeps the order of both lists is given by the binomial coefficient $$\binom{n+m}{n}$$
The time complexity of your procedure depends on various implementation details.

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more details on how you arrived at this?

Comment: It’s basic combinatorics. Once you chose the positions of the elements of the first list inside the combined list, everything else is determined (including which element of each list goes to with position).